# Creating a New Core Data Object If It Does Not Exist, or Obtaining an Existing Object if it Does Exist with Core Data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have been working on this problem now for many days and am in need of assistance because I'm not sure how to proceed. The problem I'm facing (which will become clearer as you read through this question) is I'm not sure how obtain an existing NSManagedObject if it already exists when creating a new one.

Let's take a step back to look at the Model and the premise of the app is simple; allow users to create "Transactions" which has a name, amount, occasion and date - upon creating a new Transaction, a user should be allowed to choose an existing name. The Data Model:

- Transaction Entity with wasGiven attribute
- Person Entity with name attribute
- Occasion Entity with title attribute
- Item Entity with amount attribute

The transaction has a relationship to the Person entity (whoBy), a link to the Occasion Entity (occasion) and a link to the Item Entity (itemType).

The App is a simple 2 Tabb-ed Table View Controller - the first tab contains all of the information, sectioned off by dates. The second tab contains just the "Name" information. There is a plus button and when the user presses that, they're presented with a Modal View to add in the Name, Occasion, Amount and Date. They press save and it saves it to the Core Data Database.

**Problem**
Creating a new transaction with a new name creates this perfectly. 
Creating a new transaction with an existing name (with the user manually typing in the identical name) creates a new object in the first tab as a separate entry (correct) but in the name tab, it creates a duplicate name for that person. When you click on either of the duplicate names, it shows both transactions. The problem here is that it's looking like it's creating a new Person object every time instead of referencing.

**Code**

I have gone through MULTIPLE iterations to try get this working and here is the latest code, using subclasses of NSManagedObject.

The managedObjectContext is obtained from the App Delegate.

The name, event, amount and date are stored in their own text fields.

**AddEntry.m - Save Method**

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    Transaction *transaction = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Transaction" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    Item *itemType = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    Person *p = (Person *)[Person personWithName:self.nameTextField.text inManagedObjectContext:context];
    Occasion *o = (Occasion *)[Occasion occasionWithTitle:self.occasionTextField.text andEventDate:self.dateTextField.text inManagedObjectContext:context];

    transaction.whoBy = p;
    occasion.title = self.occasionTextField.text;
    transaction.occasion = o; 


    itemType.amount = self.itemTextField.text;
    transaction.item = itemType;
    transaction.wasReceived = @(self.isReceivedSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0);
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Can't save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This of course calls the Person NSManagedObject subclass and here is where I have gone through a few iterations.

**Person NSManagedObject Subclass - Iteration 1 - Predicates**

```
+ (Occasion *)eventWithName:(NSString *)title andEventDate:(NSString *)date inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
{
    Occasion *occasion = nil; 
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Occasion"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title = %@", title];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *occasions = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (!occasions)
    {
        // Handle Error
    }
    else if (![occasions count])
    {
        occasion = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Occasion" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        occasion.title = title;
    }
    else
    {
        occasion = [occasions lastObject];   
    }
    occasion.dateOfEvent = date; 
    return occasion; 
}
```

**Problem**
This somewhat works. I placed a breakpoint and the returned "person" that gets returned here and to the save method in the Add Entry is the same if the object already exists and new if it's a new object, but when it comes to the second tab, it's still adding the a second entry for the same person.

**Iteration 2 - objectID**

With trying to obtain the Object ID, I'm getting the same result of duplicated entries in the second tab:

```
+ (Person *)personWithName:(NSString *)name inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
{
    Person *person;

    NSManagedObjectID *personID = person.objectID;

    if (!personID)
    {
        person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        person.name = name;
        return person;
    }
    else
    {
        return person;
    }
}
```

In case it matters, the second tab's fetchRequest is as follows:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Occasion" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    fetchRequest.entity = entity;
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:NO];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;
     NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

**EDIT**
I'm wondering if the fact that I don't have a predicate here in the second tab fetchRequest means it's illustrating ALL objects..

Of course, I'm future proofing this because in the first tab, when I click on a cell, I'd like to have that "Transaction" passed across so I can edit the field.

This is driving me crazy and is really stopping my app from progressing, so any assistance here would be massively appreciated!

**EDIT: Data Model Included**

[image]

Comment: Did you debug "it's still adding the a second entry for the same person" - is the same MO in the listing twice? Or you have 2 with the same name?

Comment: Hi @Wain good question - I'll have to check that - the same return person was there when using an existing name, but that doesn't mean the MO was the same - what would be the best way to debug this?

Comment: If I understand correctly "whoBy" is relation. How is it defined?

Comment: Log the `fetchedObjects` from the FRC

Comment: @AntonijoDev Absolutely - Transaction has a whoBy relationship to the Person Entity .. so transaction.whoBy.name is reaching into the Person Entity to gather the name attribute.. Person (transactions) <->> Transaction (whoBy) - hope this helps

Comment: @Wain thanks bud - will do

Comment: transaction.whoBy.name is reaching into the Person Entity to gather the name attribute

Comment: Why do you have if (!people) { // Handle error } If people is nil, that doesn't mean an error has occurred, if error is NOT nil, then an error has occurred.

Comment: @Jeff thanks for the answer - that's a good point.. should I place the "creating" code into the if (!people)?

Comment: That's correct, and if there are objects in the Array, they are your existing model objects that you need to reference

Comment: thanks @Jeff - i tried that and weirdly when it came to "saving", the name attribute was blank - so it would not create the name attribute for the table even though this was filled in on the Add Entry.. weird..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is what is happening... U add first transaction and for a name U provide Jack, then U add second transaction (T further in text) and add name John, after U add third T with name Jack and add another with name John. If U take a look at the tables in the database you will see that Transitions table has 4 entries cause You added 4 transitions, but Persons has only two. It has 2 cause you added a filter on Persons input so that it cannot contain two same names. And the mistake you made is that U tried to fetch from Transition table all entries. Of course U get 4 names (2 Johns and 2 Jacks) cause there R 4 entries in Transition table and each is associated with a Person record. If U want to fetch all persons you shouldn't fetch it from the Transition table, you should do it from Persons table OR you should add     [r setReturnsDistinctResults:YES]; on your fetch request in case U R fetching from Transition table... I think there is a way to set distinct by which property but I don't know the syntax. So the problem is really in what do You want to do, do you want to present all the persons U have in your database, or you want to present names on your transitions which means that same people could have made different transitions. See...

Comment: Bud, thanks so much - that is amazing - I feel we're getting on the right path. In the Persons table view, I want to display a list of "UNIQUE" names.. so if I have two entries for John and two for Jack, I want to see only Jack and John (once each).. then when I click on John, I go into ANOTHER table view to see All of John's transactions and I can go back to this Table view and then click on Jack and see all of his.. does this make sense? If so, in the Person Table view, would I search by Person or Transaction? Do I Apply a Predicate? What should the code be..

Comment: The fetch controlled should be the same just don't fetch from T entity, fetch from Persons entity, and in sort descriptor lose "whoBy." cause it doesn't exist in Persons, write just "name" and thats it

Comment: That works like an absolute treat! Thanks so much my friend!! :) I do have another question though (another issue) but I'm not sure if here is the right place to ask it.. In the person tab, when I select the person (which now shows ONE entry! - again thank you), it creates an exception and I suspect the reason is because in the NEW Table View that acts as the Table view when a row is selected in the Person View, I'm passing a transaction object instead of a Person - however.. I need the Transaction because I need to display other information from the Transaction links... shud I ask a new q?

Comment: I'm seeing this is causing me problems further in the app with using a Person object in the fetchRequest - is there no way I can use Just a Transaction Object, fetching the Person entity with a specific predicate to NOT display duplicates?

Comment: I already told U, U can do it on T entity but have to define distinct results like: NSDictionary *properties = [entity propertiesByName];
request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[properties objectForKey:@"whoBy.name"]];
request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

Comment: Thanks my friend - that makes sense. I'm having the same issue with the "Occasion" which has a dateOfEvent and title attribute.. I'm modifying my original question to include that code and the table view code is exactly the same as the Person but it's duplicating - any ideas why it's reacting differently?

Answer (score 0):

I persum that you have Transaction <<-Person so in Transaction managed object you have a set of persons because of the relation. When you add the same person to the Transaction it creates a new managed object and adds it to the set, and if you fetch by name you will have multiple records of the Transaction that have the same name, but that doesnt mean that you have multiple Persons. Do the fetch on Persons table directly and you will see that the values are distinct...

I recomend you instal something like Firefox and use sqlLiteManager to take a peak in the database itself...

Comment: Thanks bud - that's very interesting. That's correct in the relationship and one thing I'm noticising is, as far as I can see (new to iOS development), I'm not adding any person to any set - what code would you need to see to confirm this? 

Also, should I put a predicate in the Person fetch? If so, what should that be?

Comment: Yes U R ->  transaction.whoBy = p;

Comment: Only it does it for U

Comment: Do NSArray *arr = [transaction.whoBy allObjects]; and see the count of array on the entries with the same names

Comment: Thanks bud - sorry :) and last question - am I doing this array in the fetchedResultsController on the second tab (Person tab?).. sorry, I'm just so keen to get this sorted and a bit confused!

Comment: Ok I made a mistake, can U confirm that the relationship is: Transaction <<-Person (Person can have many transactions)

Comment: Cause this sounds like u have Transaction->>Person

Comment: ot Transaction<<->>Person

Comment: In the data model, it's like this:

Person Entity (transactions)<---->> (whoBy) Transaction Entity

Comment: I took a look at your code again, its all ok, found a bug in Iteration 2 - objectID -> U need to fetch the person to get to its id, Yous just have Person *person; and then U refer to person to get its ID, I am sure it will always be nil and U will always create new enties, maybee thats your problem

Comment: Thanks Bud - that does actually make sense - what should I do to adjust the code so that I'm fetching the person to get it's ID? Should I be specifically getting the id of the "name" attribute on the Person entity, like person.name objectID or something like that?

Comment: Also, the persontableview's fetchedresultscontroller has no predicate - should I set one because otherwise, it's displaying all?

Comment: If you are in same thread and use the same MOC then U don't really need this ID approach the one where U fetch NSManagedObjects by name is OK. ObjectID is good when U need your data in different threads and MOCs, then U just fetch objects by NSManagedObjectIDResultType and when U need object U just do NSManagedObject *object = [con objectWithID:objectID]; and U have a fresh object :)

Comment: That makes sense - soooo lost.. what's the next thing to try?? :(

Comment: I really don't know, the code looks OK to me, but the problem looks and smells like relationship issue. Just to confirm one more time, when U go to your .xdatamodel and click on the graphic preview of the database, the one where U see all your tables with their relations, U see transactions<-->>persons, cause this smels like many to many or smth like that

Comment: Agreed - I just can't figure out what's going on.. 

When I go to the Model, I see Transaction<<-->Person - I'll take a screenshot and see if I can add it to the main question here

Comment: Model Updated in the original question - hope that makes sense

Comment: Ok now I am back from my job so I can think clearly. I was right all along, U are doing everything right just don't fetch it right. Ill write new answer...